# How to increment the date in MySql inside the while loop?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to update the dates one by one using the while loop. And the date should be incremented by one day but my code is not doing this task. The table in which i want to update is **Session** table and it has composite PK **(Code+Date)** , so i want to update this date and the other part of PK which is **Code** is referencing the **code** from module table.
Here is the script to generate tables

```
CREATE TABLE course (
    `code` CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    credits TINYINT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT course_code PRIMARY KEY(`code`));
    
CREATE TABLE module (
    `code` CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    cost DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
    credits TINYINT NOT NULL,
    course_code CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT module_code PRIMARY KEY(code),
    CONSTRAINT F_code FOREIGN KEY (`course_code`) 
      REFERENCES course (`code`) 
       ON DELETE CASCADE 
       ON UPDATE CASCADE);
     
CREATE TABLE session (
    `code` CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    `date` DATE NOT NULL,
    room VARCHAR(30) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT code_date_PK PRIMARY KEY(code, date),
    CONSTRAINT F_session FOREIGN KEY (`code`) 
      REFERENCES module(`code`) 
       ON DELETE CASCADE 
       ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

```
INSERT INTO course (`code`,`name`, credits) VALUES
('WSD', 'Web Systems Development', 75),
('DDM', 'Database Design & Management', 100),
('NSF', 'Network Security & Forensics', 75);

INSERT INTO module (`code`, `name`, cost, credits, course_code) VALUES
('A2', 'ASP.NET', 250, 25, 'WSD'),
('A3', 'PHP', 250, 25, 'WSD'),
('A4', 'JavaFX', 350, 25, 'WSD'),
('B2', 'Oracle', 750, 50, 'DDM'),
('B3', 'SQLS', 750, 50, 'DDM');

INSERT INTO `session` (`code`, `date`, room) VALUES
('A2', '2021.06.05', 305),
('A3', '2021.06.06', 307),
('A4', '2021.06.07', 208),
('B2', '2021.08.22', 208),
('B3', '2021.08.23', 303),
('A2', '2022.05.01', 303),
('A3', '2022.05.02', 305);
```

Like

- 2021-06-05
- 2021-06-07
- 2021-06-08
- 2021-06-09

Here is my SP code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Modify_Schedule_5(IN courseCode Varchar(30), IN startDate date)
BEGIN

DECLARE loopCounter int;
DECLARE startDateCounter date;

SET loopCounter=(SELECT COUNT(*) from session);
SET startDateCounter=DATE_ADD(startDate, INTERVAL 1 day);

WHILE loopCounter>0 DO
UPDATE module m INNER JOIN session s on m.code=s.code
SET s.date=startDateCounter
where m.course_code=courseCode;
SET loopCounter=loopCounter-1;
SET startDateCounter=DATE_ADD(startDateCounter, INTERVAL 1 day);
END WHILE;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Code looks ok please add sample data which proves your assertion.

Comment: @P.Salmon yes everything is fine

Comment: Then please delete question..

Comment: @P.Salmon I mean code is looking good but why its not incrementing the date.

Comment: The date does increment but perhaps the update is not behaving how you think it should please add sample data and expected result as text to the question.

Comment: @P.Salmon sir i explained the question in more detail please have a look if you want i can share the database script as well. Thanks

Comment: Works as coded see https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vSRVcBahW9mkX7NJ2xpysK/0 (note data changes) if your model is different please provide sample data as text to the question.

Comment: @P.Salmon thanks a lot here is the database script link sir https://docs.google.com/document/d/1VeJ0QuILo1HQ2gLWeaULhk84I7xrmgcfWqlfTedUwKk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The link requires a sign in and account which I don't have or want..Please include everything in the question avoiding links

Comment: @P.Salmon sir i just updated the question with code please have a look. Thank you so much sir.

Comment: @P.Salmon sir ???

Comment: If you call with a parameter of wsd then a duplicate key error occurs - what do you expect the post update session table to look like?

Comment: @P.Salmon after update all the session entries against provided course code should be updated with the given date incremented by 1. after update first row we can have 2021-10-27 then 2021-10-28 then 2021-10-29 and so on

Comment: @P.Salmon sir waiting for your response. I am stuck on this issue from last 6 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the sample data is representative but the question implies you want to step thru session 1 row at a time in code and date order updating 1 row at a time. You can do this by storing the row to be updated details in variables
eg

```
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE p(IN courseCode Varchar(30), IN startDate date)
BEGIN

DECLARE loopCounter int;
DECLARE startDateCounter date;
declare voffset int default 0;
declare vcode varchar(4);
declare vdate date;

SET loopCounter=(SELECT COUNT(*) from session);
SET startDateCounter=DATE_ADD(startDate, INTERVAL 1 day);

WHILE loopCounter>0 DO
#select startdatecounter;
    select s.code,s.date into vcode,vdate 
    from module m 
    join session s on m.code = s.code 
    where m.course_code = coursecode 
    order by s.code,s.date limit voffset,1;
#select vcode,vdate;
    UPDATE module m INNER JOIN session s on m.code=s.code 
        SET s.date=startDateCounter
        where m.course_code=courseCode and s.code = vcode and s.date = vdate;

    sET loopCounter=loopCounter-1;
    SET startDateCounter=DATE_ADD(startDateCounter, INTERVAL 1 day);
    set voffset = voffset + 1;
END WHILE;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```